# How to join two arrays and join as a single nested array in jsonata

Tags: jsonata

Consider if there are two arrays like

```
["test1"], ["test2"]
```

I need result as

```
[
  ["test1"],
  ["test2"]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSONata, you can use the $append function to join two arrays. However, since you want a nested array, you'll need to wrap each of your input arrays inside another array before using $append. Here's how you can achieve this:

https://stedi.link/FH5cLbe